# Existe alguma maneira de forçar a quebra de linha dentro da tag <table>?

Tags: c#, html, css

Possuo um Select em banco que me retorna uma quantidade de registros, no caso notas fiscais, cada nota dessas possui N itens, e gostaria de fazer uma subtabela que quando for clicado, liste de maneira correta. Hoje, está dessa maneira (para 1 item funciona corretamente, para mais que isso, não desloca o segundo registro):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando existe mais de um item para determinada nota, está ficando dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O HTML está dessa maneira (Estou utilizando o padrão MVC, ou seja o HTML é minha View, e para o Model e Controller estou utilizando C#):

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="active">Nota</th>
                    <th class="active">Serie</th>
                    <th class="active">Filial</th>
                    <th class="active">Autorizado</th>
                    <th class="active">Valor</th>
                    <th class="active">Xml</th>
                    <th class="active">Danfe</th>
                    <th class="active">Itens</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var obj in Model.notasLista)
                {
                    <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="@obj.id" data-target=".@obj.id">
                        <td>@obj.nf</td>
                        <td>@obj.serie</td>
                        <td>003</td>
                        <td>@obj.autorizado</td>
                        <td>R$ @obj.valor</td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapse @obj.id">
                        <td class="info" style="width:10%"></td>
                        <td class="info">Item</td>
                        <td class="info">Material</td>
                        <td class="info">Preço</td>
                        <td class="info">Qtde</td>
                        <td class="info">Desc\Acresc</td>
                        <td class="info">Total</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapse  @obj.id">
                        <td style="width:10%"></td>
                        @foreach (var tes in Model.itensLista)
                        {
                            if (@obj.id.Equals(tes.idItens))
                            {

                                <td>@tes.item</td>
                                <td>@tes.descricaoMaterial</td>
                                <td>R$ @tes.precoItem</td>
                                <td>@tes.quantidade</td>
                                <td>R$ @tes.vlrDescontoAcres</td>
                                <td>R$ @tes.vlrTotal</td>

                            }

                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Existe alguma maneira de forçar essa quebra de linha? Como por exemplo, depois de percorrer a 1ª linha no foreach e assim sucessivamente...

Comment: Até onde me recordo, não existe uma "quebra" de linha entre as `<tr>`, o que você poderia fazer é criar uma nova `<tr>` e utilizar o atributo `colspan` nas `<td>` para conseguir a apresentação desejada.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo funcionou, vou postar no comentário para você ver como ficou! Obrigado =)

Comment: Publique a solução como uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Sou novato ainda em html então não tenho muito conhecimento sobre as tags e como utilizá-las da melhor maneira, aos poucos vou melhorando =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graças ao Leandro no comentário acima, utilizei o atributo `<colspan>` e fiz algumas modificações, que ficou dessa maneira:

Dentro do foreach para itens:

```
foreach (var tes in Model.itensLista)
{

    if(@obj.id.Equals(tes.idItens))
    {
     <tr class="collapse  @obj.id" white-space ="pre">
     <td style="width:10%"></td>
        <td>@tes.item</td>
        <td>@tes.descricaoMaterial</td>
        <td>R$ @tes.precoItem</td>
        <td>@tes.quantidade</td>
        <td>R$ @tes.vlrDescontoAcres</td>
        <td>R$ @tes.vlrTotal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"></td>
    </tr>

    }

}
```

Com isso, ficou dessa maneira quando possui mais de um item, ficou com um pequeno espaçamento, mas para mim não é problema pois deixa a mais fácil a visualização dos dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]